# I can't get the Azure Devops trigger to work

Tags: azure-devops

I will try to explain in the best way.

First situation: I didn't find any task to insert my yml file which is in ruby. If I choose Ruby, I can't edit the yaml file. If I can edit that file, I should make this trigger fire. It actually fires, not with the yml file I want

If I use the other way I can't save because I don't have permission to run pr on the master branch. My pipeline doesn't run automatically just manually

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7xvx.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgJ5H.jpg)

My yml:

```
# Ruby
# Package your Ruby project.
# Add steps that install rails, analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/ruby

trigger:
 branches:
   include:
   - homolog_gso
   
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: UseRubyVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>= 2.5'

- script: |
    gem install bundler
    bundle install --retry=3 --jobs=4
  displayName: 'bundle install'

- script: bundle exec cucumber -t @incluir_setor_resp_em_branco
  displayName: 'bundle exec cucumber'


- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'NUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    mergeTestResults: true
    searchFolder: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)'
    testRunTitle: 'Regression Test Geocall Gab'
```

Comment: The trigger you are showing here says that by committing and pushing the change in the _homolog_gso_ branch, this pipeline should be triggered. 
Did you make the change in this branch and try to push to the remote repo ?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new YAML pipeline and selecting the provided template to generate a initialized YAML file, by default this YAML file will be saved into the default branch of source repository (such as **`master`**, **`main`**).

If you do not have the permissions to directly edit files in the default branch, you are surely not able to edit the YAML file saved in the default branch.

you should copy / create the YAML to another branch where you have the permissions to edit files (e.g. **`homolog_gso`**). Then create a PR to merge the changes from this branch to the default branch.

About the PR trigger in your case, you can set the PR trigger like as below in the YAML file from the **`homolog_gso`** branch:

```yaml
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
. . .
```

By this way, if you push some changes to the **`homolog_gso`** branch and then create a PR to merge the changes to the **`master`** branch, the PR trigger will fire to run the YAML pipeline.